# pass variable arguments to functions - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I defined a function that can take any number of arguments but none is required:

```
function MyFunction() { //can take 0, 1, 1000, 10000, n arguments
//function code
}
```

Now i would like to write another function that call MyFunction with a variable number of arguments each time:

```
function Caller(n) {
var simple_var = "abc";
MyFunction() //how can i pass simple_var to MyFunction n times?
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should not name your functions uppercase as long as they are no constructors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Function.apply` can be used to pass an array of arguments to a function as if each element in the array had been passed as an individual argument:

```
function Caller(n) {
   var simple_var = "abc";

   // create an array with "n" copies of the var
   var args = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      args.push(simple_var);
   }

   // use Function.apply to send that array to "MyFunction"
   MyFunction.apply(this, args);
}
```

Worth to say, [argument length is limited to 65536](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80797) on webkit.

Comment: 1. Use args[args.length] instead of args.push() 2. Your solution submits an array as parameter, not n different parameters.

Comment: @Amberlamps - `apply` is used for this very situation. It will submit `n` arguments

Comment: @Amberlamps you're wrong - `.call` is used to send it as an array, `.apply` to send it as a list of parameters.

Comment: @Amberlamps also there's negligible performance difference between `array.push()` and `args[args.length]` - see http://jsperf.com/array-push-and-append-by-index

Comment: @Alnitak: Lol, I picked up a different statistic a while ago, but I cannot find it anymore. That proves again that you cannot really trust the internet :)

Comment: @Amberlamps you shouldn't use `shift` or `unshift` unnecessarily because they require the remaining elements to be renumbered, but `push` and `pop` are very efficient.

Answer (score -3):

You can use eval (I know, eval is evil).

In for loop construct string:

```
var myCall = "Myfunction(abc, abc, abc)";
```

and then pass it to eval

```
function Caller(n) {
var simple_var = "abc";
  eval(myCall);
}
```

Comment: never, ever, ever, use `eval`.